# Batch rename files on Mac with specific decimal

Tags: macos, shell, rename

I have about 6 folders of files, about 4000 video clip files that need renaming to match the files in the project - my files are named for instance:
CAM0-00001.mp4

However the video project was worked with and had files named:
CAM0-0001.mp4

The Mac default renamer can only rename batch files with 5 decimal points, one too many.

Comment: Can you please start here? [Minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is an interesting information about the Mac renamer... So?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from your question whether you want to introduce an additional zero after the dash, or whether you want to remove a zero following a dash, so I'll show you both. Please make a backup before trying this - it is a very powerful command!

You will need `rename`, a.k.a. Perl rename, which you can get on macOS with:

```
brew install rename
```

Then the command to remove a zero after the dash on all `mp4` files in the current directory is:

```
rename --dry-run 's/-0/-/' *mp4
```

**Sample Output**

```
'CAM0-00001.mp4' would be renamed to 'CAM0-0001.mp4'
```

---

The command to add an extra zero after the dash on all `mp4` files in current directory is:

```
rename --dry-run 's/-/-0/' *mp4
```

**Sample Output**

```
'CAM0-0001.mp4' would be renamed to 'CAM0-00001.mp4'
```

If it all looks correct, remove the `--dry-run` and run it for real.