AppleScript, Why is my my code taking so long to run?
I'm trying to change the names of files through a system of networks.
Most concert folders contain files that have been mislabelled.
This script renames the files with the specific issue.

Folder: 20100523-ConcertName
FileName: 20100523-SongNumber-SongName.wav -> 20100523-ConcertName-SongNumber-SongName.wav

There's two locations I want to change the names of (And I can't change this).

specificQuarterFolder - a folder of 30 or so concerts
generalMp3Folder - a folder full of thousands of concerts throughout the years, but I'm only trying to change the files found in the specficQuarterFolder

When testing with 10 or so folders of files, it runs in an instant. But running it on the system, it takes hours and eventually crashes.
# Set to the destination of a Specific Quarter. Ex: "Desktop/Fall 2010"
set specificQuarterFolder to "/Volumes/concert_archive/concert_archive_combined/2010_Fall"
set destination to "/Users/music-production/Desktop/Scripts for Renaming/2010_Fall_RenameLog.txt"

# Set to the destination of the general MP3 Folder
set generalMp3Folder to "/Volumes/concert_archive/concert_archive_mp3"

set combinedArchiving to (POSIX file specificQuarterFolder) as text
set mp3Archiving to (POSIX file generalMp3Folder) as text
set logFile to (POSIX file destination) as text

global logFileRef
global counter
set counter to 0

set specfic to "Selected Quarter: " & specificQuarterFolder
set general to "General: " & generalMp3Folder
set dialogResult to display dialog specfic & return & general & return & "Do you want to continue?" buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"

on changeFileNamesAtPath(folderPath, concertName, extensionName, type)
    set changedFileCounter to 0
    set oldDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"-"}
    
    tell application "Finder"
        set songFiles to files of folder folderPath whose name extension is extensionName
        set songFileNames to name of every file of folder folderPath whose name extension is extensionName
    end tell
    
    repeat with i from 1 to count of songFiles
        set songFile to item i of songFiles
        set fileName to item i of songFileNames
        set splitString to text items of fileName
        
        -- Assuming Concert names will never be 2 characters
        set secondItem to item 2 of splitString
        if (length of secondItem) is equal to 2 then
            set newName to concertName & text 9 thru -1 of fileName
            tell application "Finder"
                set name of songFile to newName
            end tell
            
            set counter to counter + 1
            set changedFileCounter to changedFileCounter + 1
            set logEntry to "    " & counter & " [" & type & "] " & fileName & " -> " & newName & linefeed
            write (logEntry) to logFileRef
        end if
    end repeat
    
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
    
    if type is not equal to "Joint MP3s" and changedFileCounter is not equal to 0 then
        write (return) to logFileRef
    end if
    
    return changedFileCounter
end changeFileNamesAtPath

if button returned of dialogResult is "Continue" then
    set logFileRef to open for access logFile with write permission
    set eof logFileRef to 0 -- Clear the file
    try
        tell application "Finder"
            set concertList to name of folders of folder combinedArchiving
        end tell
        
        repeat with concert in concertList
            write (concert & return) to logFileRef
            set concertPath to (combinedArchiving & concert & ":") as text
            
            try
                set stereo96Path to (concertPath & "Stereo 96:") as text
                set stereoCount to changeFileNamesAtPath(stereo96Path, concert, "wav", "Stereo 96")
            end try
            try
                set mp3Path to (concertPath & "MP3:") as text
                set mp3Count to changeFileNamesAtPath(mp3Path, concert, "mp3", "MP3")
            end try
            
            -- Changing the Other MP3 Folder
            try
                tell application "Finder"
                    set targetMP3Concert to (first folder of folder mp3Archiving whose name is concert)
                end tell
                if targetMP3Concert is not missing value then
                    set secondMp3Path to (mp3Archiving & (name of targetMP3Concert) & ":") as text
                    set secondMp3Count to changeFileNamesAtPath(secondMp3Path, concert, "mp3", "Joint MP3s")
                else
                    set secondMp3Count to 0
                end if
            end try
            
            try
                if mp3Count is not equal to stereoCount or mp3Count is not equal to secondMp3Count then
                    write ("Unbalanced Changes" & return) to logFileRef
                end if
            end try
            
            write ("=====Done=====" & return & return) to logFileRef
        end repeat
        
        close access logFileRef
        
    on error errMsg
        try
            close access logFileRef
        end try
        display dialog ("Error: " & errMsg) buttons {"OK"}
    end try
    
    set display to "Files Changed: " & counter
    set youCanFind to "You can find all the changed Files Here"
    display dialog ("Files Changed: " & counter & return & youCanFind & return & destination) buttons {"OK"}
end if


The problem for RuntimeError? I'm thinking it's the "whose" function that is trying to find  each one of the 30 or so concerts in the thousands of folders. I am new to AppleScript, what should I do differently?
Or is it because both of these locations are not on the local computer but connected through NAS drives (Network Attached Storage)?


It's impossible to tell from here but a couple of thoughts… If it works properly for a modest number of files but performs poorly for a large number, then perhaps using the Finder is the issue. System Events can improve performance when working through expansive folder structures. Using 'try' statements and handlers reduces feedback. Try removing the try statements (except for the write commands) and see what effect this has. I'd do these things and also comment out the renaming commands to see what files are being designated for renaming.

@Mockman Oh my gosh, you're quite right. I'm so sorry, I misread what you wrote.  I apologise.  I will remove the comment and repost it and the proceeding ones to amend my mistake.

@Mockman Is correct about using System Events over Finder for filesystem operations. And he makes a good point about the misuse of try blocks that shouldn't be used to plaster over brittle elements of a badly written script. As @Mockman states, the feedback is useful and fixing the code by attending to the cause of errors produces a robust script. Error catching also slows execution. try is appropriate with your use of write commands because its specific purpose isn't to avoid termination, but rather to close open file handles for a safe termination. Cont'd...

...Cont'd The main reason for the slow running time is, indeed, down to your whose filters. Although they are efficient in many cases, you're using them wrongly, and performing the same filtering operations multiple times needlessly: in declaring the variables songFiles and songFilesNames, you enumerate every file in a folder twice. Later, you request the first folder of folder mp3Archiving whose name is concert, but it's much better to tell the folder named mp3Archiving to tell the folder named concert to if it exists then set targetMP3Concert to it Cont'd...

...Cont'd You are also correct that operating on a network drive will be slower, but that's unavoidable. The bottleneck is your code. Some minor bits: 1) If concertPath is text, and you concatenate (&) it with "Stereo 96:", which is also a piece of text, there's no need to coerce the result of this to text. Coercions aren't free even when it seems like nothing happens. 2) You're obsessively constructing your file paths using text processing, rather than filesystem operations that target a folder, which would be quicker and more robust. Cont'd...

...Cont'd 3) Your stated objective is to change file names of the form "%d-%s-%s.wav" to "%d-%s-%s-%s.wav". But concertName & text 9 thru -1 of fileName omits the numerical prefix. Checking (length of secondItem) is 2 is sketchy. Instead, check splitString has exactly 3 items, and use these to build a new list into which concertName is inserted as the second item. When coerced to text, the text item delimiters re-insert the hyphens automatically. So: Cont'd...

...Cont'd tell the splitString to if length = 3 then set newName to {item 1, concertName, item 2, item 3}'s contents as text. This is more robust and faster. 4) Finally, constructing a whose filter predicated on the evaluation of a property, e.g. name extension can be intensive and slow compared.  It sounds counter-intuitive, but a faster method would be to enumerate the name of every file and loop through them to discard the ones that don't end with ".wav". In this case, text processing is faster using ends with over filtering against a property. ☐

You seem to want to change filenames from DATE-SONGNUMBER-SONGNAME to DATE-CONCERTNAME-SONGNUMBER-SONGNAME, is that correct? If so, I would recommend the rename program which you can install with homebrew using brew install rename.  Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908215/2836621 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59247526/2836621
